# How to set onclick parallel with swipe in viewpager?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Here I have developed an app to view full screen images. I was able to develop it with swipe to move to next image. I have used a viewpager element.
How can I use onclick action to viewpager to do something.(delete, share etc..)

My code looks like below,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen);

    Thread child=new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            utils = new Utils(getApplicationContext());

            Intent i = getIntent();
            int position = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);

            adapter = new FullScreenImageAdapter(FullScreenViewActivity.this,utils.getFilePaths());
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);//show the selected

            btnMail=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMailThis);
            btnRate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRate);

            btnMail.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            btnRate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



        }
    };
    child.start();
}
```

The FullScreenImageAdapter.java looks like below

```
public class FullScreenImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Activity _activity;
private ArrayList<String> _imagePaths;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

// constructor
public FullScreenImageAdapter(Activity activity,
        ArrayList<String> imagePaths) {
    this._activity = activity;
    this._imagePaths = imagePaths;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this._imagePaths.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    TouchImageView imgDisplay;
    //Button btnClose;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_full_image, container,
            false);

    imgDisplay = (TouchImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
    //btnClose = (Button) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imagePaths.get(position), options);
    imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    /* 
    // close button click event
    btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            _activity.finish();
        }
    });*/

    ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout);

    return viewLayout;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

}
```

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class inheriting ViewPager and override onInterceptTouchEvent like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(arg0.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        //Your code here
        return false;

    } else {
        //Do this to keep swipes working. It will also make vertical swiping work. You can avoid the latter by handling MotionEvent action and x,y directions.   
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(arg0);
    }

}
```

Don't forget to replace the ViewPager object in your xml with `com.example.yourpackagename.YourViewPagerClass`

Comment: Note: `ViewPager2` **is** final, so it **cannot** be inherited from. `ViewPager` **is not** final, so it **can** be inherited from.